# INCreateNoteIntent groupName always null

Tags: sirikit, ios11, swift4

When creating a note with Sirikit, I can resolve the title and the content but not the groupName. Siri understands the folder name but po intent always returns groupName = "".

```
func resolveGroupName(forCreateNote intent: INCreateNoteIntent, with completion: @escaping (INSpeakableStringResolutionResult) -> Swift.Void) {
    if let groupName = intent.groupName {
        NSLog("%@", groupName)
        completion(INSpeakableStringResolutionResult.success(with: groupName))
    } else {
        completion(INSpeakableStringResolutionResult.needsValue()) //endless loop
    }
}
```

This only happens in the simulator. On the device it is not asking for a folder name and not stopping at break points. Is it not possible to debug siri extension on device?

It seems to be a problem with the sentence. If I put this siri query directly in the schema, it is working in the simulator and I see the correct group name 'f' in the log:

```
Create a note called c in my f folder saying s in myappname
```

but not if I replace f or s. Is there any error in the sentence? Where can I find examples of correct sentences?

I took this from the WWDC Presentation:

```
Create a note called WWDC in my presentation folder saying SiriKit in UnicornNotes
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the sentence you are giving to Siri ?
You can find a great tutorial here : http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/enabling-siri-integration-sirikit/